# Election results ?

Tags: support, election

Looks like the election is over ! I tried downloading the recommended software and figuring out the results, but it had so many options and flags that it confused me, so I have no idea. Do we know when the results will be announced and the new moderators will be "crowned" ?

Comment: @Suresh, It seems that you will be the king. Congratulations in advance :)

Comment: eh, ok. I guess. but did you see something official ?

Comment: I have an unofficial result which I obtained by using a different program http://votesystem.sourceforge.net/ which also uses the Meek STV, but I would like to wait for the official announcement.  It will not take long, hopefully?

Comment: it is the weekend, so I imagine it might take till Monday to set the mod bits on the winners.

Comment: That is a good point.  Should I post the unofficial result here?  I am reluctant to do so because the real result may be different for various reasons (different options in counting, my misunderstanding of the ballot file format, my misunderstanding of how to use the program, bugs in either program, etc.).

Comment: that's exactly why I didn't post it either. let's just wait for the official word.

Comment: Ok, I will wait.

Answer (score 15):

The result is available on the [election](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/election/1) page.  Congratulations, Suresh, Kaveh and Dave!

*Update*: The three elected candidates have become moderators.  Congratulations again.  Hope you will enjoy the duty. :)  Also, let me thank to Ryan Williams for serving us as one of the first two moderators, and Sadeq Dousti, Hsien-Chih Chang (張顯之), Neel Krishnaswami, Aaron Sterling and Lev Reyzin for volunteering themselves as moderator candidates.

Comment: Yeah, congrats to the new mods!

Comment: Thanks, I hope that I will make a good moderator, and that you two will get over +10K soon and gain access to mod tools, that would make the life easier for us. :)

Comment: Looks like the site will be in good hands!

Comment: @Kaveh: That will be in far future, but I will try anyway. :)

Comment: Nice post Tsuyoshi. You'll make a great mod. I hope you have more free time in the next election, and you nominate yourself too.